# How to center map in gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

i want to display a map centered to a specific location.
In my controller, I use

```
@gmapsoptions = {
     "map_options" => {"center_latitude" => 40, 
                       "center_longitude" => 73,
                       "detect_location" => false,
                       "center_on_user" => false,
                       "auto_adjust" => false,
                       "auto_zoom" => false,
                       "zoom" => 8 }
                 }
```

and in my view i use

```
<%= gmaps(@gmapsoptions) %>
```

It renders the map just fine, but it is not centered on the location specified above but on "0/0" aka the dateline.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. But I'm using the (stable) branch I'm working on https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/tree/objectify_js

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am using gmaps4rails 1.5.5 and did what you recommended in [link](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/201) . When I click the generated link in Chrome, it shows: 'alert("Ihre Anfrage wurde vom Google Maps-API-Server abgelehnt. Der in der Anfrage angegebene \x22sensor\x22-Parameter muss entweder \x22true\x22 oder \x22false\x22 sein.")' which roughly means 'sensor \x22 in request must be true or false'. But it is set, so why do i get this error?

Comment: Don't know and can't reproduce... Any public url?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. No, I don't have a url 'cause i am fairly new to rails (i know: sigh). to reproduce this, i have created a new blank project, included the gem, `rails generate scaffold user name:string address:string latitude:float longitude:float` , `rails generate gmaps4rails:install` and followed the instructions on github. still the same behaviour :-(...

Comment: Push it on github and guve me the link

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses and your help for a noob. You can find the repo here: [link](https://github.com/c-ern/gtest).

Comment: Short update: I created an initializer for not escaping js urls. Still the same behaviour. Only Chrome does not show the alert in sourcecode anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked your repo, you should simply have `auto_zoom` set to `true` (or remove it since it's the default value).

Comment: i feel a little embarrassed - now it works just fine. I fiddled around with nearly all the other parameters... thanks for your patience. btw: on the first look, it does not seem to work with openlayers. but I think your project mainly addresses gmaps and that works like charm now for me.

Comment: Good news :) I should receive some help for openlayers, hopefuly!

Comment: i'll keep my fingers crossed! great gem and great support! thanks!

Comment: supposedly if i want to zoom in plus want to show a certain region in map then how shall i do it

Comment: @AayushKhandelwal: please ask a question, it's unreadable in comment

Comment: this worked for me too, but I don't understand why.  Why does setting auto_zoom to true make centering to work ...?